# Android:reverse geocoding-how to save the address for later use?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, locationmanager, reverse-geocoding

I am building a project which needs users current location.I am using reverse geocoding to get the exact address of the user.I am using asynctask to run the thread finding the exact address in background.This is my code:

```
package com.prince.geolocationtest;


import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {
    TextView text, text2, text3;
    LocationManager location;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        location = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
        criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
        criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
        criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
        criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
        String bestProvider = location.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        try {
            location.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.e("Permission_Exception", "Permission Not granted");
        }
        // text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Provider=" + bestProvider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    public void AddDisp(String add) {
        text3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        text3.setText(add);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double lon = location.getLongitude();
        AsyncTry obj = new AsyncTry(this);
        obj.execute(lat, lon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        switch (status) {
            case 0:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Out Of Service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Temporarily Unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is off", 3).show();
        Intent GPSIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(GPSIntent);
    }

    public class AsyncTry extends AsyncTask<Double, Integer, String> {
        Context context;
        String add;

        public AsyncTry(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {


            try {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                str.append("Latitude:" + params[0] + "\nLongitude:" + params[1] + "\n");
                if (geocoder.isPresent()) {


                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(params[0], params[1], 1);
//                 str.append("Address:"+addresses.get(0).getLocality());
//                 str.append("\n"+addresses.get(0).getAdminArea());
//                 //String zip = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
//                 str.append("\n"+addresses.get(0).getCountryName());
                    if (addresses != null) {

                        Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);


                        for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            str.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                        }
                    }
                    add = str.toString();
                    //str.toString();

                } else {
                    add = "Geocoder implementation doesnt exists";
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception:", e.toString());
            }
            MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                Location loc;

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    text2.setText(add);
                }
            });

            return add;
        }


        protected void onpostExecute(String result) {
           // super.onPostExecute(result);

            if (result != null) {
                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                text.setText(result);
                AddDisp(result);
//          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }


    }

}
```

Though the program returns the address and displays it in the main thread using `runOnUiThread`, I am not able to send the address to `onPostExecute` method of `asyncTask`. I need to use the address for later use rather than just displaying it.. how can I do that?  I am using android studio IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit()
    .putString("ADDRESS", add)
    .apply();
```

To get it from SharedPreferences:

```
String address = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).getString("ADDRESS", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared `onPostExecute` incorrectly. It should be like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute (String result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just rewrote your AsyncTask a little bit. You should pass the TexView you want to display the address to the AsyncTask. Does it work now ?

```
public class AsyncTry extends AsyncTask<Double, Integer, String> {

    Context context;
    TextView textView;
    String add;

    public AsyncTry(Context context, TextView textView) {
        this.context = context;
        this.textView = textView;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Double... params) {
        try {
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
            str.append("Latitude:" + params[0] + "\nLongitude:" + params[1] + "\n");
            if (geocoder.isPresent()) {
                List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(params[0], params[1], 1);
                if (addresses != null) {
                    Address fetchedAddress = addresses.get(0);
                    for (int i = 0; i < fetchedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                        str.append(fetchedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    }
                }
                add = str.toString();
            } else {
                add = "Geocoder implementation doesnt exists";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception:", e.toString());
        }
        return add;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result != null) {
            textView.setText(result);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Then what about the method I am calling from onPostExecute with the address as parameter??